Update a selection of dataframe rows based on set of ids taken from a different dataframe
I have a dataframe_original df that has data from the database, snippet below:
id,str_id,partition,type,class,side,quantity,trade_price_normalized,m_g,m_s
1,t1,52816001,1,CLASS1,1,10.0,10.0,,
2,5o1,52816001,5,CLASS1,1,10.0,10.0,,
3,6o1,52816001,6,CLASS1,1,10.0,10.0,,
4,t2,52816001,1,CLASS1,1,10.0,12.0,,
5,5o2,52816001,5,CLASS1,1,5.0,12.0,,
6,5o3,52816001,5,CLASS1,1,5.0,12.0,,
7,6o2,52816001,6,CLASS1,1,5.0,12.0,,
8,6o3,52816001,6,CLASS1,1,5.0,12.0,,
13,t5,52816001,1,CLASS1,1,30.0,30.0,,
14,t6,52816001,1,CLASS1,1,20.0,30.0,,
15,5o5,52816001,5,CLASS1,1,22.0,30.0,,
16,5o6,52816001,5,CLASS1,1,13.0,30.0,,
17,5o7,52816001,5,CLASS1,1,15.0,30.0,,
18,6o5,52816001,6,CLASS1,1,22.0,30.0,,
19,6o6,52816001,6,CLASS1,1,13.0,30.0,,
20,6o7,52816001,6,CLASS1,1,15.0,30.0,,

┌─────┬────────┬───────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────┬────────────────────────┬──────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ str_id ┆ partition ┆ type ┆ class     ┆ side ┆ quantity ┆ trade_price_normalized ┆ m_g  ┆ m_s │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---                    ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64       ┆ i64  ┆ str       ┆ i64  ┆ f64      ┆ f64                    ┆ List[str]  ┆ List[str] │
╞═════╪════════╪═══════════╪══════╪═══════════╪══════╪══════════╪════════════════════════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ t1     ┆ 52816001  ┆ 1    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 10.0     ┆ 10.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 2   ┆ 5o1    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 10.0     ┆ 10.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 3   ┆ 6o1    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 10.0     ┆ 10.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 4   ┆ t2     ┆ 52816001  ┆ 1    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 10.0     ┆ 12.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 5   ┆ 5o2    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5.0      ┆ 12.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 6   ┆ 5o3    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5.0      ┆ 12.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 7   ┆ 6o2    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5.0      ┆ 12.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 8   ┆ 6o3    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5.0      ┆ 12.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 9   ┆ t3     ┆ 52816001  ┆ 1    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5.0      ┆ 20.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 10  ┆ t4     ┆ 52816001  ┆ 1    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 5.0      ┆ 20.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 11  ┆ 5o4    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 10.0     ┆ 20.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 12  ┆ 6o4    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 10.0     ┆ 20.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 13  ┆ t5     ┆ 52816001  ┆ 1    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 30.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 14  ┆ t6     ┆ 52816001  ┆ 1    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 20.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 15  ┆ 5o5    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 22.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 16  ┆ 5o6    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 13.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 17  ┆ 5o7    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 5    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 15.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 18  ┆ 6o5    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 22.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 19  ┆ 6o6    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 13.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │
│ 20  ┆ 6o7    ┆ 52816001  ┆ 6    ┆ CLASS1    ┆ 1    ┆ 15.0     ┆ 30.0                   ┆ []   ┆ []   │

During the data processing I do
.group_by(['partition', 'class', 'side', 'trade_price_normalized', "type"])
            .agg([
                pl.sum('quantity').alias('quantity'),
                pl.col('str_id').alias('str_id'),
                pl.col('id').alias('id')
            ])

After all processing is done, a dataframe is returned, where ids such as 13 and 14 both have quantity of 50, instead of 30 and 20 as in original dataframe (due to .agg()).
│ 13  ┆ t5           ┆ 52816001       ┆ [1]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["5_5", "6_5"] ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] │
│ 14  ┆ t6           ┆ 52816001       ┆ [1]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["5_5", "6_5"] ┆ ["5_1", "6_1"] │
│ 15  ┆ 5o5          ┆ 52816001       ┆ [5]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["1_5"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 16  ┆ 5o6          ┆ 52816001       ┆ [5]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["1_5"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 17  ┆ 5o7          ┆ 52816001       ┆ [5]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["1_5"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 18  ┆ 6o5          ┆ 52816001       ┆ [6]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["1_5"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 19  ┆ 6o6          ┆ 52816001       ┆ [6]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["1_5"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │
│ 20  ┆ 6o7          ┆ 52816001       ┆ [6]            ┆ CLASS1 ┆ 1    ┆ 50.0000000000  ┆ 30.000000000000        ┆ ["1_5"]        ┆ ["1_1"]        │

The result of this processing is new values in m_s and m_g columns for some of the rows.
I want to run further processing on a dataframe with original quantity column and udpated m_s and m_g.
Therefore I need to either:
a) revert the quantity column to original state after data processing
b) update values of original_dataframe in columns m_s and m_g but only for ids that are present in processed dataframe.
What I've done is I save the original quantity column as a series:
original_quantity_series = df_db.to_series(6)
Then I concat the processed part of the dataframe to the unprocessed part of the dataframe (I filter for rows that are unchanged) and re-assign the quantity column:
df = pl.concat([df_processed, df], rechunk=True)
df = df.with_columns(quantity = original_quantity_series)

The problem with this is that sometimes I need to sort the dataframe by type column. When I concat the dataframes and sort, the order changes sometimes while the order of saved original quantity column doesn't - so there is a mismatch. Also it's probably very suboptimal.
I've found polars.DataFrame.update but it's marked as unstable so I don't want to use it.
Given that I have the copy of dataframe_original and dataframe_processed returned from processing function, what's the best way in polars to do something like:
for id in dataframe_processed['id']:
   dataframe_original['m_s'] = dataframe_processed['m_s'] # for rows with matching id.

I guess it's achievable with expressions API and pretty quick if done right.
Alternatively how to use the .agg function like so to get both the original quantity column and aggregated one:
.group_by(['partition', 'class', 'side', 'trade_price_normalized', "type"])
            .agg([
                pl.sum('quantity').alias('agg_quantity'),
                pl.col('str_id').alias('str_id'),
                pl.col('id').alias('id')
            ])
            .select([
            "id",
            "str_id",
            ....
            "quantity",
            "agg_quantity"
            ])

The code above always throws an error no such column as quantity, only agg_quantity is present.
EDIT: simpler example:
Original dataframe:
id,quantity,m_s
1,10.0,f
2,20.0,f
3,30.0,f
4,40.0,f
5,50.0,f

Processed dataframe:
id,quantity,m_s
1,10.0,a
3,60.0,c
4,80.0,e

Processed dataframe contains new values for m_s column and some values in quantity colum have changed. For ids present in processed dataframe, I want to udpate the values of m_s column in original dataframe (only m_s, not quantity column), so the result would be:
id,quantity,m_s
1,10.0,a
2,20.0,f
3,30.0,c
4,40.0,e
5,50.0,f


Your example is a bit complicated, but you probably need to look at Expr.over()

Also, it's interesting that you say you have id in processed DataFrame, while based on your code it looks like id is going to be aggregated list of id from original DataFrame.

@RomanPekar I explode later so nothing is really aggregated.
I provided a simpler example in edit in main posit, it really boils down to this easy simplification after I think about it.

If you are worried about the stability of update, but it otherwise does what you want, you can copy paste its current implementation from https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/py-1.5.0/py-polars/polars/lazyframe/frame.py#L6328-L6559

You have id and str_id inside agg - why don't you include quantity also? But as mentioned .group_by().explode() can be done with .over() inside .with_columns() - The simplified example ignores the fact the "2nd dataframe" is infact just the group_by of the "1st dataframe". It's basically a different question than the original, so you will get different answers.

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you could just use join():
(
    df_original
    .join(df_processed, how="left", on="id")
    .with_columns(m_s = pl.coalesce("m_s_right", "m_s"))
    .drop("m_s_right", "quantity_right")
)

┌─────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ quantity ┆ m_s │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ str │
╞═════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10.0     ┆ a   │
│ 2   ┆ 20.0     ┆ f   │
│ 3   ┆ 30.0     ┆ c   │
│ 4   ┆ 40.0     ┆ e   │
│ 5   ┆ 50.0     ┆ f   │
└─────┴──────────┴─────┘


You can use pl.DataFrame.update.
df.update(df_processed.drop("quantity"), on="id")

shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ quantity ┆ m_s │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ str │
╞═════╪══════════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10.0     ┆ a   │
│ 2   ┆ 20.0     ┆ f   │
│ 3   ┆ 30.0     ┆ c   │
│ 4   ┆ 40.0     ┆ e   │
│ 5   ┆ 50.0     ┆ f   │
└─────┴──────────┴─────┘

Edit. I just noticed that you referred to update already in the question. From the docs:

This is syntactic sugar for a left/inner join, with an optional
coalesce when include_nulls = False

